# How to set Windows Authentication on database imported into SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server

Database cannot be seen when creating datasource in .NET - pre-existing databases can be seen.

How do I set the permissions on the imported database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you imported the database from another instance of SQL Server, the users in the database are probably not being mapped correctly to the login on server. Even though they may have the same name, SQL Server will give each user a unique ID for that specific server.

The fastest way to resolve the issue is to delete and recreate the users for your database using [SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx) or Enterprise Manager.

Comment: Thank you. Never easy, I guess.